# HTML5 Tile Engine

Tags: html, canvas, 2d, tile-engine

Where can I find a tile engine for HTML5 `<canvas>`, for writing 2D games?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Possibly: http://www.effectgames.com/effect/ and in particular http://www.effectgames.com/effect/#Article/docs/Sprites_and_Tiles_Guide
However note that effect is free to use but proprietary and not open source.

Other Javascript/Canvas game engine libraries that would make it easy (but may not have specific tile support/documentation):

- http://github.com/kesiev/akihabara
- http://gamejs.org/
- http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/
- http://gamequery.onaluf.org/

Sites you might want to follow:

- [Mozilla Labs Gaming](http://mozillalabs.com/gaming/)
- [Badass Javascript](http://badassjs.com/)

Comment: Did you find one you liked?  I'm anxiously awaiting the Isogenic engine: http://www.isogenicengine.com/

Comment: Seems EffectGames is open-source now and on github: https://github.com/jhuckaby/Effect-Games

Answer (score 1):

This site compares a few well.

http://city41.github.io/breakouts/

Answer (score 0):

This engine, called [Tile](https://github.com/ajschlosser/Tile), is a work in progress. If anything, it might give folks looking to write their own engines a few ideas about what to do (or what not to do, if you prefer).