# Find engine to develop html5 games in 2d or 3d isometric with tiles?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 3d, game-engine

With friends we want to develop a html5 canvas videos games in 3D isometric games or 2D.

After some research I found this: http://canvasengine.net.

It's seems clear, easy , documented ...

What do you think about this lib? You have another lib to recommend?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)  You question probably is a better fit for stackoverflows sister site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.  Stackoverflow is more technical question & answer.  The programmers site dives into "what's the best ...".  Even so, here is a site with a good variety of game engines you can check into: http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/javascript-html5-game-engines-libraries-51-examples/

Comment: Don't worry, we will use canvaengine :p

Answer (score 4):

Canvasengine seems a decent project to me.

Some other relevant links here on SO:
[HTML5 Tile Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961189/html5-tile-engine)
[2D Engines for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172191/2d-engines-for-javascript)

There is also [gameJS](http://gamejs.org/) that has support for '[tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/)' to!

I kind of liked [gameQuery](http://gamequeryjs.com/) to.